# Not able to comment on my own answer

Tags: support, comments

I have enough reps but I am unable to comment on my answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628805/twitter-desktop-client). What's the problem?

Comment: Is it giving you any error message?

Comment: @Mitch nope, nothing happens when I click "Add Comment"

Comment: @Ron nuke your browser cache, cookies, everything, then login and try and comment.  It should be giving you an error message along the lines of rep or such but if it's not i wonder if you have old site data there that you need to clear out

Comment: @ThomasW.No luck. Can the OP disable comments?

Comment: @Ron - comments works on it here in Firefox - which browser are you using?

Comment: @Wilf I am using latest Chromium browser from ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Does it work in FireFox?